# What are some best practices with setting database foreign keys

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys

What are some good rules of thumbs and pitfalls that database designers should watch out for when setting up foreign key constraints in a database?

Also, when inheriting an existing database with few foreign keys, how difficult is it to just add foreign keys onto an existing schema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't allow nulls in foreign keys
- Avoid using DEFERRABLE constraints even if your DBMS supports them.
- Consider adding the ON UPDATE CASCADE option if you think you must but also consider the alternatives (insert then update rather than directly update the candidate key).
- Be aware that adding a constraint is often harder than removing it. Adding constraints is probably more likely to break existing code (some DML may not work) and therefore potentially requires more development and testing time to fix. For that reason it's better to add constraints earlier rather than later in every development cycle - you can always remove them later.

Comment: Why, in the world, is deferrable bad? -.5

Comment: Because actually deferring a constraint means that the constraint is not enforced. Any code in that transaction could see the database in an inconsistent state, which defeats the purpose of applying the constraint in the first place.

Comment: that's absolutely incorrect. a deferred constraint is only deferrable until the transaction commits. At that point every constraint is then checked. To every other session the database is completely consistent. the reason for a deferred constraint is to allow a child record to be created BEFORE the parent. But the parent has to be there before the commit.

Comment: @Stephanie, what you say is correct and is the same as what I said. The code within the current transaction will see the database in an inconsistent state. The consequences of that can even persist beyond the current transaction if other tables without deferred constraints are modified or if other code is called. Deferring a constraint therefore defeats the purpose of the constraint which is to maintain (declarative) consistency at all times so that the programmer doesn't have to worry about doing so in procedural code.

Comment: That's an extremely simplistic view of programming and constraints. There are cases where adding the child before the parent is not only simpler but the only possible logic. The programmer doesn't HAVE TO do any more or less consistency maintenance in their procedural code. INSERT Parent; INSERT Child; Commit. or DEFER; INSERT child; INSERT parent; Commit. Explain why the second case is bad and how that has persistent ripples to other tables.

Comment: Of course you *can* still write code which is unaffected by the database being in an inconsistent state. The point is that you wouldn't have to if SQL didn't force such an undesirable thing on you. Multiple assignment is a must-have for effective enforcement of many business rules. If SQL supported multiple assignment then deferred constraints would be unnecessary. Even your simple example exhibits the problem. In your second "INSERT parent" any code called by the INSERT will see the database in an inconsistent state and so may need to be structured to handle those inconsistencies.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would bring up what SQL doesn't do. I live and program on this planet with the things that SQL does. And yes programming is full of challenges but the challenge presented by the absence of deferred constraints is much great than their use. Without deferring a constraint my database would still be an inconsistent state. INSERT phony-parent; INSERT child pointing to phony parent; INSERT parent; UPDATE child to real parent. That's **JUST** as inconsistent if not worse.

Comment: Oops, forgot to add DELETE original phony parent... that's a good demonstration of why it's worse.

Answer (score 3):

Rule of thumb, never set up a relational database without the foreign key relationships if you care about the integrity of your data. Yes this can slow dow data inserts/updates and deletes some. This is a good thing as it is taking actions to protect your data. Without data integrity **all** of the data in your database is untrustworthy and therefore useless.

It is generally not hard to set up foreign keys later (in SQL Server you run an Alter table statment to add the key), the difficulty in doing so is the reason why it is unprofessional to not add them in the design phase. If you didn't have an FK, it is highly likey that you have some data that doesn't meet the rules of the PK/FK relationship and that needs to be cleaned up first.

Comment: While I agree that it's good practice to use foriegn keys, i wouldn't go so far as to say that your data is useless without them.  There are good reasons to not use foreign keys in certain situations, particularly if you need to later purge some data without affecting other data that would normally contain an FK relationship.  Business rules don't always follow data rules.  However, those situations are extremely rare.  I'm simply saying that not having an FK doesn't make your data useless, although it can make it suspect.

Comment: The data isn't useless, but you can't prove that. With enabled constraint you can say any time of the day for a fact, that the integrity isn't compromised. This is powerful. As a bonus the optimizer makes use of constraint. I actually argue that constraints and RI makes databases faster on average, rather than the other way around ;)

Comment: If you don't know the dat is correct, it is useless. That doesn't mean it isn't being used anyway and consequently bad decisions are being made as a result of using bad data.

Comment: Agreed that "without data integrity" data isn't much use. However, foreign keys are only one kind of data integrity. Just because you aren't using foreign keys that doesn't mean your data has no integrity.

Comment: If you aren't using foreign keys, you don't know if your data has integrity and therefore it is useless.

Comment: @HLGEM: "If you aren't using foreign keys..." That doesn't really follow. There are other aspects of data integrity too, potentially more important to data integrity than foreign keys - for example uniqueness and domain constraints. It seems quite reasonable in appropriate cicrumstances to have an accurate model with integrity without FKs.

Comment: @HLGEM: Also, FOREIGN KEYS as implemented in SQL are only capable of implementing certain RI constraints and not others. So if lack of RI makes your data "useless" then some models will be condemned always to be useless! In reality, most data models in SQL implement only a subset of the business rules that would actually constitute a full set of data integrity constraints. The database designer needs to decide which constraints are most important and practical to enforce.

Answer (score 2):

- When you inherit a schema, you *will*
  have to add constraints to it. (Not just foreign key constraints.)
- Someone will have to fix bad data
  before you can add constraints.
- It takes people a long time to fix
  bad data. (They have "real" work to
  do.)

The first database design job I did as a professional was to replace an existing database for a Fortune 500. It was small, even for the 1980s. A couple of administrative people were assigned to fix data errors uncovered during analysis and design. They could fix a couple hundred errors a day. They didn't want all the errors at once, just a couple hundred a day.

So I fed them a couple hundred errors a day. Every day for six months.

Comment: I'd like to think this is a worse-case scenario. *Often* you'll hit situations like this, but not always.

Comment: It's really annoying actually, because it only takes 1 error to make it impossible to enable the constraints and enjoy the awesome optimizer transformations that are available for some of the more complicated queries.

Comment: I *like* to think it's a worst-case scenario. But I've seen it happen too many times; I think it's about average for a legacy conversion.